# How to reuse templates

Tags: go, go-templates

I'm trying to get into web-development in Go, and so far I've figured out to nest templates and passing in variables. But is there a way to reuse templates? I'm thinking along the lines of creating a new template from an existing one, and passing in variables unique for each.

Take for instance this template:

```
{{define "btn"}}
<button type={{.Type}} class={{.Class}} title={{.Title}}>
    {{.Name}}
</button>
{{end}}
```

Would the be a way to create new static templates from "btn", and use them somewhat like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>A button</h1>
    <div>{{template "btn-version-1"}}</div>
    </div>
    <h2>Another button</h2>
    <div>Some content {{template "btn-version-2"}}</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But I feel that I'm barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Nested_template_definitions

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I can see I was looking in the wrong direction.


" If it's necessary to have a template addressable from multiple associations, the template definition must be parsed multiple times to create distinct *Template values, or must be copied with the Clone or AddParseTree method."